Errors in nand2tetris hardware simulator
I am currently in a course that is covering nand2tetris tools and such, and I got my first homework to implement a few chips but none of them seem to work, I get an error msg for every chip I try. This is my first time even dealing with something like this so I'd appriciate any feedback and corrections.
Chip 1 - it's supposed to multiply the input by 2, ERROR: Chip out[0] is not found in working and built in folders
    IN in[16];
    OUT out[16];
    
    PARTS:
    out[0] = 0;
    out[1] = in[0];
    out[2] = in[1];
    out[3] = in[2];
    out[4] = in[3];
    out[5] = in[4];
    out[6] = in[5];
    out[7] = in[6];
    out[8] = in[7];
    out[9] = in[8];
    out[10] = in[9];
    out[11] = in[10];
    out[12] = in[11];
    out[13] = in[12];
    out[14] = in[13];
    out[15] = in[14];
}

Chip 2 - supposed to return the number of bits in which the two inputs differ, ERROR: line 6: diff[0], sub bus of an internal node may not be used
    IN a[16], b[16];
    OUT out[16];
    
    PARTS:
    Xor(a=a[0], b=b[0], out=diff[0]);
    Xor(a=a[1], b=b[1], out=diff[1]);
    Xor(a=a[2], b=b[2], out=diff[2]);
    Xor(a=a[3], b=b[3], out=diff[3]);
    Xor(a=a[4], b=b[4], out=diff[4]);
    Xor(a=a[5], b=b[5], out=diff[5]);
    Xor(a=a[6], b=b[6], out=diff[6]);
    Xor(a=a[7], b=b[7], out=diff[7]);
    Xor(a=a[8], b=b[8], out=diff[8]);
    Xor(a=a[9], b=b[9], out=diff[9]);
    Xor(a=a[10], b=b[10], out=diff[10]);
    Xor(a=a[11], b=b[11], out=diff[11]);
    Xor(a=a[12], b=b[12], out=diff[12]);
    Xor(a=a[13], b=b[13], out=diff[13]);
    Xor(a=a[14], b=b[14], out=diff[14]);
    Xor(a=a[15], b=b[15], out=diff[15]);
    
    Add16(in = diff, out = out);
} 

Chip 3 - returns the number of zeros in a row starting with the MSB, ERROR: line 8, Can't connect gate's output pin to part
    IN in[16];
    OUT out[16];      

    PARTS:
    
    And(a=in[15], b=true, out=out[0]);  
    And(a=in[14], b=out[0], out=out[1]); 
    And(a=in[13], b=out[1], out=out[2]); 
    And(a=in[12], b=out[2], out=out[3]);
    And(a=in[11], b=out[3], out=out[4]);
    And(a=in[10], b=out[4], out=out[5]);
    And(a=in[9], b=out[5], out=out[6]);
    And(a=in[8], b=out[6], out=out[7]);
    And(a=in[7], b=out[7], out=out[8]);
    And(a=in[6], b=out[8], out=out[9]);
    And(a=in[5], b=out[9], out=out[10]);
    And(a=in[4], b=out[10], out=out[11]);
    And(a=in[3], b=out[11], out=out[12]);
    And(a=in[2], b=out[12], out=out[13]);
    And(a=in[1], b=out[13], out=out[14]);
    And(a=in[0], b=out[14], out=out[15]);

}

I am very new to this so I know they're not the most optimal or even correct solutions but those are my only ideas.

I would suggest you carefully read the appendices of the NAND2Tetris book regarding the format and restrictions of HDL.
For example, you can't directly connect an input and an output as you are doing in Chip 1. The list of PARTS must be exactly that, a list of parts (sub-chips) that are wired together. So there must be at least one part between each input and output. The "ERROR: Chip out[0] is not found in working and built in folders" is being generated because the HDL compiler is expecting to see a list of chips, so it expects the first token ("out[0]") to be a chip name, and no such chip exists.
Moving on to Chip 2, the error message tells you exactly what the problem is: you cannot create an internal bus from the output of multiple chips. You can, however, have each of the chips generate a single bit output (ie: diff0, diff1,...) and then specify what bit of a chip input bus they are connected to (ie: Add16(in[0]=diff0,in[1]=diff1,...). Also, Add16 adds two numbers together which is not what you're trying to compute as far as I can tell.
Finally, in Chip 3, you're doing the same thing as in Chip 2 but with the output bus instead of an internal bus, and again, it looks like you're trying to output a bit position rather than a count of bits.
